# Xamarin Forms Highlight Selected Image Area and Carry certain action on Click

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

My Overall Requirement:

- There is a static image of human body part (head, nose, eye, ear, shoulder, biceps, hand, thigh, ankle, chest, stomach, etc.) as shown in attached image
- Need the feature to SELECT each body part and the selected part should be HIGHLIGHTED on CLICK
- After clicking on each body part, it should perform specific action (eg. Inserting health status of each body part)
- The body part position should be same across all devices having different resolutions, so that the tapped coordinate is uniform among all resolution devices

Can you please help me, how can I achieve above requirements in Xamarin Forms (for both Android and iOS) ?

Body Parts Image:
[image: img]

Comment: How I would do it would be to add a boxview on top of the image in the various desired positions, you would probably have to use a relative layout and it will need some testing to make sure they are in the correct spot. Then make these boxviews transparent and a touch gesture event to them

Comment: Box view might be too complex for our project, since the image parts (body parts) are not of regular shape.
The region indicating hair, nose, ear, etc. is of irregular shape and hard to obtain through box view.
We need to highlight the entire selected part despite being irregular shape.

So, can you please suggest how can we highlight the selected image area if the area is of irregular shape like hair, nose, eye, etc ?

Comment: My apologies I didn't realize that you wanted it exactly over the body part. I would then use a geometry to create an object to create a clickable object over the image. The tricky part will be to get the geometry. If the image is an . svg you can get the path from a program like inkscape

Comment: Yes! And then add a gesture recognizer to it so that tapping on it launches an event

Comment: Hey, what option did you go with? Would love to know.

Comment: Have you solved this ? I am now facing the exact same challenge